# Linear Dependency

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hey everyone, I'm having trouble with this problem. Asking for linear dependency means that the determinant has to be 0. So I'm assuming we can take the three vectors given and put them in a matrix? I'm just confused as to how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $u,v,w$ are linearly independent, no combination of them can equal $0$.

So for the set $S$ to be linearly dependent, the only way is for the three vectors to be added in such a way that $u,v,w$ are cancelled out.

This can be achieved only as $$(u-4v)+4(v-2w)+8(w-ku)=0$$
Which yields $k=\frac{1}{8}$.

Answer (score 0):

As for how to do this with determinants: relative to the basis $\{u,v,w\}$ (of a subspace of $\Bbb R^7$), we can write the the vectors in question as
$$
\pmatrix{1\\-4\\0},\pmatrix{0\\1\\-2},\pmatrix{-k\\0\\1}
$$
we would then verify that the matrix with these columns has determinant $0$ if and only if $k = 1/8$.